# How to pass data suring a redirect in a ApiController?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-apicontroller, .net-4.7.2

I have a simple upload method (POST) that happens on `/home/import` address:

```
//public class HomeController : ApiController

[HttpPost]
[Route("import")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Import()
{
    //Upload logic, multi-part data...

    Redirect(new Uri("/home", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

After uploading, I need to redirect the to the previous page (/home), but passing a boolean and a string content to the model, to display if the upload was successful or not.

How can I pass data to the previous page model?

I don't have access to `TempData` as stated in other posts.
I understand that I may have to tap into a `IHttpActionResult` to handle that.

Comment: An HTTP Redirect tells the browser to call another URL. It doesn't pass any data back to the browser. Depending on the specific code, the browser will send the original body in the POST request. If you want the previous page to load new data, you'll have to load that data there, based on the new query parameters

Comment: Yes, I ended up passing the data via URI query. Thanks.